# I need to add the values in my database using Insert button on the form but I am having an exception of "Syntax error near word onto"

Tags: c#, sql

```
private void b1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Inam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication8\WindowsFormsApplication8\Student.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(s);
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert valujes into record("+int.Parse(T1.Text)+",'"+T2.Text+"'"+int.Parse(T3.Text)+",'"+T4.Text+"'",cn);
        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("New record added succesfuly");
            cn.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception )
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record could not be added");

        }

    }
```

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

Comment: C? C doesn't have 'private', 'string', 'try-catch', 'new', etc. Did you mean **C++**?

Comment: This is not C++ either. Did you mean **C#**? It uses the verbatim operator (`@`), uses `object` which is a reserved word in C#, and does not use explicit pointers when dealing with the `new` operator.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a typo in word `valujes` in your SQL-Command (should be `values`).

Anyway, usually such things are tackled by printing the effective SQL-command, which you build by string concatenation, on the console and try it out in interactive SQL.

In your case, write

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert valujes into record("+int.Parse(T1.Text)+",'"+T2.Text+"'"+int.Parse(T3.Text)+",'"+T4.Text+"'",cn);
std::cout << cmd << std:endl;
```

and have a look at the console then. Usually you will find out that the SQL-command looks suspicious; and you can copy/paste into interactive SQL from there.

BTW: I think the syntax is `insert into mytable values ("  ", 223)`, right? Have a look at the position of your `"values"`-keyword.

Comment: To be fair, the question isn't C-related either.

Comment: By the way, the code posted in the question is not C++. Methods are not defined with the visibility modifier in the declaration (ie. `private void f() {...}` or `public int g() {...}`) and the `new` operator returns a pointer which would require `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("...")` to become `SqlCommand* cmd = new SqlCommand("...")` to work in C++. I think this code is actually C#.